# jQuery validate resetForm error when I close dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery validate: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ and cannot reset the validation messages to a default state. ie; not highlighted. What I trying to achieve, is if I close my dialog window, then the validator resets itself to a state as if the window was first opened. What is happening however, is when I close dialog by clicking the X and reopen, the error messages are still there. I am not sure where resetForm() should go and if I have to prepare a dialog ("close") procedure.

I have only posted the code that I think is relevant to the problem.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Thanks

```
else if (this.name === 'Administration') {
    $("#formShow").show();
    // admin clicked

    //$("#confirm_department").show().html("You have selected administration");
    $("#formImage .col_1 li").hide();
    var $dialog = $('#frmreport');
    $dialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Submit a ' + name + ' report',
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: true,
        // buttons: {
        // Close: function() {
        // $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        // $("#frmreport").get(0).reset();
        // }
        // }
    });
    //$( '#frmreport' ).dialog( 'close' );
    //$("#frmreport").get(0).reset();

    //console.log(name);
    $('input[name=dept]').val(name);
    $(".subtitle").text("Submit " + name + " feedback report");
    //code   
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated code as per your comment

```
else if(this.name === 'Administration') {

            $("#formShow").show();

           // admin clicked


             //$("#confirm_department").show().html("You have selected administration");
             $("#formImage .col_1 li").hide();
             var $dialog = $('#frmreport');
               $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               modal: true,
               title: 'Submit a ' +name+ ' report',
               width: 500,
               height: 400,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: true,
               Close: function(event, ui) {
               $("#frmreport").validate().resetForm();
               }
               // buttons: {
               // Close: function() {
               // $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        // $("#frmreport").get(0).reset();
               // }
               // }
               });
        //$( '#frmreport' ).dialog( 'close' );
                //$("#frmreport").get(0).reset();

                //console.log(name);

             $('input[name=dept]').val(name);
             $(".subtitle").text("Submit " + name + " feedback report");

          //code   
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `Close` function:

```
 $dialog.dialog({
    close: function(event, ui) {
               $("#frmreport").validate().resetForm();
           }
 });
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I do not want to use a button to close the form because I send data to submitHandler that handles serailize etc. Is it possible to have a close function without a button. Thanks

Comment: Still the same problem. Thanks

Comment: You should substitute #formreport with the id of your form

Comment: I made a mistake, it's `validate` not `validator`

Answer (score 1):

This is the working solution !

```
 var $form = $('#userForm');
        $form.find("[data-valmsg-replace]")
               .removeClass("field-validation-error")
               .addClass("field-validation-valid")
               .empty();
```